# how to get property from code behind jquery variable?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to retrieve property value in jquery function and want to set it in variable. I am trying with below code but its not working.

.cs file

```
private string _Heading;
public string Heading { get { return _Heading; } set { _Heading = value; } }
```

.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e) {
        ShowDialog(false);
        e.preventDefault();
        var someProp = "<%= this._Heading; %>";
       alert(someProp);
      });
 </script>
```

What should i do to retrieve property value?? Anyone have solution than please help me in this.

Comment: can we see the HTML markup of `#btnShowSimple` ? I don't work with cs, but if you want to get the property of any element, you simply do `$(this).prop('someProp')`. If in the markup the element has a prop called `_Heading`, you could use `$(this).prop('_Heading')`

Comment: what are you seeing in javascript page source with current code?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I am not accessing button's property. I am accessing class(i.e. CS file's) property.

Comment: @charlietfl: Nothing. It throws an error.

Comment: The _Heading variable is private so you won't be able to access it - why are you not using the Heading property?

Comment: This works var someProp = "<%=this.Heading%>";

Comment: Have you also removed the semi colon after Heading?

Comment: @KevinMain: Semi colon was the problem..

Comment: @KevinMain: make these comments into an actual answer so that it can a) be voted up and b) be marked as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if the variable is private you will not be able to access it in your JavaScript so you should use the public Heading property instead.

Secondly, you have a semi colon in your JavaScript which needs to be removed so change this line

```
var someProp = "<%= this._Heading; %>";
```

To this

```
var someProp = "<%=this.Heading%>";
```